# How to create a counter id in React.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I do count that will be updated in real-time, the problem is that I can not give him the id, to be unique for each page.

```
<ViewCount counterText="views" firebaseHost="https://boiling-fire-123.firebaseio.com/" firebaseResourceId=??? />
```

My backend on ruby-on-rails.

Help

[React component](https://github.com/hashobject/react-count.git)

Comment: I don't see how this is an issue with React. It seems you would have the same problem if you didn't use React? If you want to generate unique IDs based on the page, take the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `firebaseResourceId` on componentDidMount or getInitialState of ViewCount object.

Or you could generate it on parent level of ViewCount and pass it by props.